# Sesion caduca antes de los valores fijados en web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web

Que tal Devs,
    Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion Web forms con asp.net, no logro hacer que la sesion no caduque antes de 20 minutos, tengo una pantalla de login en donde al momento de autenticarme guardo en una variable de sesion el usuario autenticado, esto lo hago asi para mantener la sesion dentro del sistema (se que no es la forma mas correcta), el asunto es que pasado 20 minutos de inactividad me regresa al login, lo otro es que por alguna razon si estoy trabajando dentro del sistema pasado los 20 minutos tambien me saca del sistema, como puedo resolver esto, adjunto codigo fuente de las configuraciones de como manejo la sesion:

web.config:

pantalla del login:

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string sUsuario = tbUserName.Text;
        string sPassword = tbPassword.Text;
        DataSet dsUsuario;


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sUsuario) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPassword))
        {

            try
            {
                if (objControllerSeguridad.AutenticarUsuario(sUsuario, sPassword))
                {
                    dsUsuario = objControllerSeguridad.DsReturn;
                    if (dsUsuario.Tables["Usuario"].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Session["usuario"] = dsUsuario.Tables["Usuario"].Rows[0]["USUARIO"].ToString();
                        Session["nombreUsuario"] = dsUsuario.Tables["Usuario"].Rows[0]["NOMBRE"].ToString();
                        Session["idRol"] = dsUsuario.Tables["Usuario"].Rows[0]["ID_ROL"].ToString();
                        Session["rol"] = dsUsuario.Tables["Usuario"].Rows[0]["ROL"].ToString();

                        Response.Redirect("~/", false);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FailureText.Text = "Usuario o Clave incorrecta.";
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        return;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    FailureText.Text = "Ocurrio un error, consulte con el administrador del sistema.";
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                    return;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError(ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace);

            }


        }

    }
```

Y en el master page es donde controlo que la variable de sesion de usuario que no haya caducado:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var sCookie = Request.Cookies["Cookie"].ToString();

```
            //if (Session["usuario"] == null || Session["idRol"] == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(sCookie))
            if (Session["usuario"] == null || Session["idRol"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx");
            }else
                BuildMenu(dxMenu, SqlDtsBanco);
            if(dxMenu.SelectedItem != null)
                Session["id_menu"] = dxMenu.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx");
            //Session.Abandon();
        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Podrias configurar el tiempo de expiracion de `Session` del sitio

[Modos de estado de sesión](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178586.aspx)

la idea es que cambies en el `web.config` el tiempo

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"
      stateConnectionString="tcpip=SampleStateServer:42424"
      cookieless="false"
      timeout="20"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

podrias aumentarlo para que el tiempo, pero recuerda que el tiempo de inactividad se toma cuando no se realiza ninguna invocacion al servidor, puedes estar trabajando en el browser pero si nunca viaja un request expirara la session

Podrias aplicar sino esta tecnica

[[ASP.NET] Mantener la Session Activa Indefinidamente](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2010/07/aspnet-mantener-la-session-activa.html)

alli explico como por medio de ajax puede invocar al server para evitar que expire

Comment: Y para ASP.NET MVC 5? También habría que mantener "la cookie de autenticación" para Forms, que tiene su timeout.