# Como aumentar tiempo de espera Session asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas Estoy realizando mi proyecto para que dure 2 horas la sessión es decir un ejempl.
que si el usuario ingresa y lo deja despues de 2 horas no se debe de cerrar . 
actualmente cada vez que pasa 45 min cuando el cliente realiza o va a otra pestaña se le redirecciona al login .

yo quisiera que despues de 2 hora se realiza eso. aumentar el tiempo de session.

**Global.asax**

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["username"] = "username";

        Session.Timeout = 5000;
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
    }
```

**WebConfig.**

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;"/>-->
    <!-- <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />-->
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;deleteAfterServicing=false;privateImages=false" />
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;deleteAfterServicing=true;"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="525600"></sessionState>

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
          assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="9000000" maxRequestLength="999999999"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Ws_UsuarioSoap" sendTimeout="20.00:00:00" maxBufferSize="999999980"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="999999980" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:65213/Ws_Usuario.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Ws_UsuarioSoap" contract="Ws_Usuario.Ws_UsuarioSoap"
        name="Ws_UsuarioSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**en todas mi pagina en el load estan asi. es decir si la sesion es igual username se redirecciona al login**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["username"].ToString() == "username")
            { Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveUrl("~") + @"Seguridad/CerrarSession.aspx"); }

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                llenarGrilla();
            }
        }
```

Comment: podes mostrar todo el global asax ?

Comment: @LucianoMontañez claro ahi esta hermano ya lo edite en mi pregunta

Comment: Deberias ver este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153581/how-do-you-change-session-timeout-in-iis-8-5

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Comment: @fredyfx no mi hermano

Comment: Podrías ejecutar un script que se ejecute en segundo plano, básicamente haría un refresh. Esto sería mediante la invocación a un .ashx Te envío el link donde se explique de forma detallada el proceso y el funcionamiento. https://geeks.ms/jalarcon/2008/06/11/cmo-evitar-que-la-sesin-caduque-por-inactividad/ También podrías revisar el siguiente post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106144/sesion-caduca-antes-de-los-valores-fijados-en-web-config?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

El tiempo esta en segundos, asi que puedes poner ese numero

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="7200"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```